# PHP request user data during execution of a script

Tags: php, api, telegram, tdlib

I have a problem and I do not know how to solve it. I am working with PHP and the TDLib library to manage the Telegram API, for this, I make asynchronous calls through the JSON interface:

https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started#tdlib-interface

The Telegram API works through updates. The program receives the Telegram updates that must be answered properly in the order they are received. For this, I have a script with a 'while' cycle that works correctly for me. Here is an example of the algorithm:

```
void *client = td_json_client_create();
// somehow share the client with other threads, which will be able to send requests via td_json_client_send
const double WAIT_TIMEOUT = 10.0; // seconds
int is_closed = 0;  // should be set to 1, when updateAuthorizationState with authorizationStateClosed is received
while (!is_closed) {
  const char *result = td_json_client_receive(client, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
  if (result) {
    // parse the result as JSON object and process it as an incoming update or an answer to a previously sent request
  }
}
td_json_client_destroy(client);
```

Well, the problem is that at any given time the update status of the API is *"Waiting for phone number"*, at which time the user should be asked for the phone number. Subsequently, after several update states, Telegram sends a code to that phone number, so again my application must request the user to enter the received code when the status of the API is *"Waiting for the code"*.

For this, I programmed **two forms**, one to request the phone number and another to request the code. The problem is that the forms **are not shown until the script finishes**, which does not help.

I tried to handle the flow of the script with *break* or *return* as the case may be, and this time I get the forms displayed at the right time, but the expected execution of the script ends, after sending the forms it becomes to execute all the code from the beginning, restarting the variables.

Anyway, I hope I have explained correctly and so that someone can give me better advice because I am really lost.

Comment: The snippet you show needs to answer the http request from PHP in a non-blocking manner, is that correct?

Comment: If so, it is the only solution that occurs to me, I do not know if there will be another possibility.